# Best way to have non-root user execute script with commands that require root access?

Tags: bash, shell-script, permissions, sudo

I have a script that is executed by php so it runs as the www-data user. The script is pretty simple, it basically copies some pre-made files such as the hosts and interfaces files to the correct directories. Maybe update some permissions etc.

I thought creating a new user and giving that access to the required commands only through `visudo` might work but

1. that still requests the user executing the `.sh` for a password and
2. it plainly does not give the test user permissions.

`visudo` (all permission denied when running `./script.sh`)

```
test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
test ALL=      NOPASSWD:ALL
test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/cp,/bin/mv,/bin/nano,/bin/chown,/bin/mv
```

When I change the `test` user to the actual user I'm logged in with, it works.

`.sh` executed by the logged in/`www-data` user trying to execute the commands as a different user with the required permissions.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -H -u test cp test.txt /etc/test.txt
sudo -H -u test chown test /etc/test.txt
echo "ok"
```

What is the best way to enable the `www-data` user to execute a script that requires `root` permissions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understood you, but if you want to run a script whose internals require sudo to execute, wouldn't this work ? --- `$ sudo bash -c "./script.sh [arg1[ arg2]]" ` where arg1, arg2 are optional script arguments.   You may want to add the optional `sudo` flags: `-E` to preserve the user's environment variables, `-u test` to specify that user `test` runs the command. Just make sure that `test` is part of the `sudo` group and that your script is executable. If this suits you,there is no need to modify your `sudoers` file in a way that makes your system vunerable to attacks.

Comment: In fact, there is **never** a need to make your system vulnerable to attack ... unless you are building a honey pot of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sudoers` part you have shown does not make sense.

```
test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
test ALL=      NOPASSWD:ALL
test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/cp,/bin/mv,/bin/nano,/bin/chown,/bin/mv
```

You want just one of these lines, probably the last one.

Executing `echo "ok"` with no respect to the exit code of the earlier commands doesn't make much sense either.

As far as you have shown there are no `sudo` permissions for the user `www-data`.

On a normal system `sudo -H -u test cp test.txt /etc/test.txt` doesn't make sense because the user `test` cannot create files in `/etc`. This would only work if the target file exists and has write permissions for the user `test.

However, `sudo -H -u test chown test /etc/test.txt` never makes sense because the only user which can call `chown` that way successfully is root.

### solution

I guess what you need is this. A script

```
#!/bin/bash

cp ~test/test.txt /etc/test.txt &&
    chown test /etc/test.txt    &&
    echo 'ok' || echo 'failure'
```

1. Put that script in a path that is writable only by `root`
2. Create a `sudo` permission like this

   ```
   www-data ALL= NOPASSWD:/path/to/script.sh
   ```
3. Call the script as `www-data` like

   ```
   sudo /path/to/script.sh
   ```

Comment: Apologies for the unclear explanation. My script will be called from php exec. I figured out sudo needs to be in that command for things to work. Combined with your recommendations my script now appears to run.

Am I correct thinking that every command inside script.sh will be executed as root? I've set chown root:root script.sh and chmod 755 script.sh, will this make things reasonably secure?

Comment: yes, all commands in script.sh will be executed as root. Your chown and chmod look good. Please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @sjaak The script itself is not dangerous; it could even be allowed for every user to execute (as root). It does not contain confidential information. Thus it is not a problem that it is world-readable. It is rather useless, though, to make it world-executable as it would not work anyway. So no problem but as a general rule it may make sense to make sudo scripts readable for `root` (and admin groups) only.